# SQL return results only if all rows match in join

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists, full-outer-join

I have the following tables

```
table name               column names
-----------              ------------------------
delivery_ service        svc_name | svc_cost
product                  prod_id 
service_prod             svc_name | prod_id
order                    order_id
order_item               order_id | prod_id
```

Now I want to calculate the total delivery service cost (`svc_cost`) of all items in an order. Of course, this total makes sense *only* if all items in the order are eligible for that delivery service.

For instance, product `fresh tomatos` only have `express` delivery service, whereas product `dvd` has both `express` and `normal shipping` as delivery service. Consequently, the delivery cost of an order with items `fresh tomatos` and `dvd` should only take `express` delivery service costs into account, since `normal shipping` is not eligible for the total of the order.

I'm not sure how I should translate this into SQL.

Any tips on where to start are welcome

Comment: You didn't mention the expected result when the service isn't the same for all items in the order.  Provide a complete test case, `CREATE TABLE` statements, `INSERT` statements, for just enough rows to show the cases you care about. Then show the exact result you expect, given that data.  Provide any SQL you've attempted and the corresponding wrong result.  That's the starting point, a complete test case, so you can evaluate your logic.

Comment: What if all items support all delivery methods?

Comment: If there are only 2 delivery methods "express" & "normal" then, as I understand it, it would be 2 bundels. 1st bundel with all that have an "express" and 2nd bundel for those with only a "normal". Correct?  But what if there are non with only "express", then all send "normal"? Urgh, this won't be an easy SQL puzzle.

Comment: This really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Just an untested notepad scribble in anticipation of clarifications.

```
SELECT order_id, product_count
, CASE
  WHEN strictly_express_cost = 0 THEN strictly_normal_cost + whatever_normal_cost
  WHEN strictly_normal_cost = 0 THEN strictly_express_cost + whatever_express_cost
  ELSE strictly_express_cost + strictly_normal_cost + whatever_normal_cost
  END AS total_cost
FROM
(
    SELECT order_id
    , SUM(CASE WHEN express_cost > 0 AND normal_cost = 0 THEN express_cost ELSE 0 END) AS strictly_express_cost
    , SUM(CASE WHEN express_cost = 0 AND normal_cost > 0 THEN normal_cost ELSE 0 END) AS strictly_normal_cost
    , SUM(CASE WHEN express_cost > 0 AND normal_cost > 0 THEN express_cost ELSE 0 END) AS whatever_express_cost
    , SUM(CASE WHEN express_cost > 0 AND normal_cost > 0 THEN normal_cost ELSE 0 END) AS whatever_normal_cost
    , COUNT(DISTINCT prod_id) AS product_count
    FROM
    (
      SELECT orditm.order_id, orditm.prod_id
      , SUM(CASE WHEN svcprd.svc_name = 'express' THEN dlvsvc.svc_cost ELSE 0 END) AS express_cost
      , SUM(CASE WHEN svcprd.svc_name = 'normal' THEN dlvsvc.svc_cost ELSE 0 END) AS normal_cost
      FROM order_item AS orditm
      LEFT JOIN service_prod AS svcprd 
        ON svcprd.prod_id = orditm.prod_id
      LEFT JOIN delivery_service AS dlvsvc 
        ON dlvsvc.svc_name = svcprd.svc_name
      GROUP BY orditm.order_id, orditm.prod_id
    ) q1
    GROUP BY order_id
) q2
```